# Is it possible to get the key when it is found in array?

Tags: php, array-key-exists

Is there a better way to get a key from an array if it is found in case-insensitive search?

The logic of the code I need is like below:

```
<?php
$search = "foo";
$array = array('Foo' => 1, 'Boo' => 2);

if (array_key_exists($search, array_map('strtolower', $array)))
    return "Foo";
?>
```

Approach I would like to improve:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists($search, array_map('strtolower', $array)))
{
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
    if ($search == strtolower($k))
        return $k;
    }
    unset ($k, $v);
}
?>
```

Comment: The array can be multi-dimensional as well?

Comment: No, I'm looking for one-dimensional arrays solution only. Thanks

Comment: `if (array_key_exists($search, array_map('strtolower', array_keys($array))))`

Comment: `if (!empty(array_filter($array, function($key) use ($search) { strtolower($key) == $search; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = ['a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'C' => 3];
$search = 'c';

$result = array_filter($a, function($k) use ($search) {
  return strtolower($k) != $search;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = "foo";
$array = array('Foo' => 1, 'Boo' => 2);

function get_value($array, $search) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($search === strtolower($key)) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function get_key($array, $search) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($search === strtolower($key)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo get_value($array, $search);
var_dump(get_key($array, $search));
```

I believe you're looking for this approach.

Hope it helps!